# What is the best way to get consistent logs from search queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a web app with entries from Google sheets. They are loaded into an array of objects. I hooked up miniSearch to it.

What is the best practice to get search queries from the end-user that are consistent and not "cut"?

My current code gets everything in the searchbar 1,5 seconds after the last keystroke. It works, but I'm wondering if it could be improved.

```html
<input id="search" class="form-control me-2 w-50" type="search" aria-label="Search">
```

```js
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let debounceTimer
  return function() {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
    debounceTimer
      = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay)
  }
}

$('#search').on('keyup', debounce((e) => {
  STATE.searchQueries.includes(e.target.value) ? null : STATE.searchQueries.push(e.target.value)
}, 1500))
```

Comment: Dropping the debounce to 250ms should still be more than enough

Comment: from this it appears your logging like would log  like so >"h", "ha", "ham", "hams", "hamst", "hamste", "hamster" ? this may be a stupid question so apologies, why not log the search when the user clicks the search button or if this is part of some sort of autocomplete then log when the response comes back with a list of options and the user selects one, that way you can log the entire search word and not just part of however many letters have been typed in at the time?